# Regex that doesn't match spec.ts and spec.tsx but should match any other .ts and .tsx

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I wrote this regex that matches any .ts or .tsx file names but shouldn't match spec.tsx or spec.ts. Below is the regex I wrote.

```
(?!spec)\.(ts|tsx)$
```

But it fails to ignore.spec.tsx and spec.ts files. What am I doing wrong here? Please advice.

Comment: What is the regex flavor?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The negative lookahead syntax (`(?!...)`) looks *ahead* from wherever it is in the regex. So your `(?!spec)` is being compared to what follows that point, just before the `\.`. In other words, it's being compared to the file extension, `.ts` or `.tsx`. The negative lookahead doesn't match, so the overall string is not rejected as a match.

You want a negative *lookbehind* regex:

```
(?<!spec)\.(ts|tsx)$
```

Here's a [**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/aA3lK3/1) (see the "unit tests" link on the left side of the screen).

---

The above assumes that your flavor of regex supports negative lookbehinds; not all flavors of regex do. If you happen to be using a regex flavor that doesn't support negative lookbehinds, you can use a more complex negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*spec\.tsx?$).*\.tsx?$
```

This says, in effect, "Starting from the beginning, make sure the string doesn't end in `spec.ts` or `spec.tsx`. If it doesn't end in that, then match if it ends in `.ts` or `.tsx`"

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/pH4zP9/2)